# groovy: save gsp state

Tags: grails

I have 2 gsp's say, "a.gsp" and "b.gsp".

"a.gsp" have combobox, from which user can select options.

My question is that, if the user shift to "b.gsp" and then come back to "a.gsp", the combobox selected option should be still there.

How to achieve this ?

Comment: What 'come back' do you mean? User pressed 'back' button?

Comment: @Igor Artamonov - it means navigate to same page through menubar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it sounds like you are not fully embracing Grails' MVC architecture and using controllers correctly to prepare data and pass structured data through to your view.

To begin with, rename your controller actions and views to something meaningful rather than a,b. Even if just for testing a small sample, as taking shortcuts can lead to long term bad habits...

Secondly, if you are using a  tag then you would use the value attribute to indicate what should be selected.

Read about the tag and its attributes here : http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Tags/select.html

Give us more details and perhaps we can help.

---

Thanks for the clarification,  so I'm assuming that there could be any number of ways a user might leave the current a.gsp page and come back, but whatever happens you want the browser to remember the selected option.  In this case I would use the jQuery cookie library, its very small, won't impact performance as you're doing very litte work and should be very quick for you to setup..  See: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

1. Set a cookie in an onChange handler based on your selects val() value.
2. When your page loads (document ready), if you get a value when reading the cookie, then try and set the select value.

Comment: I am using meaningful names in my project. For explanation purpose i used a and b.
Anyway, my question is not related how to use select tag.
It is about if in combobox i have selected any value, then i navigate to another page after that if i came back to same page, it should display the previous selected value.

Answer (score 2):

You can do multiple things to achieve this. Depending on your requirements you may:

- Use javascript and cookies.

  Pass the value selected in the combobox into the controller when you naviate to b.gsp and into a hidden field in b.gsp, but then you have to pass it back to the controller once more when you want to see a.gsp.

  Pass the selected value inside session/flash scope

Comment: Rather than cookies, you can also use LocalStorage, which is supported in most modern browsers. Much more performant than cookies.

Comment: As Atharva Johri says, Grails offers no help in remembering selections in forms, unlike wicket which does this for you via the session.  I have not found a good way to do this.  I ended up writing a lot of manual code, to save each value into the session for my most important forms, and manually pull out this data and push it back into the form via the forms controller.  I guess it might be possible to write a more generic solution which you can put into all your controllers.